# Text caret behavior in BiDi context

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable, right-to-left, bidi

I'm having a hard time understanding how the caret is handled in a `contenteditable` context with BiDi/RTL text by modern browsers.

The purpose of this question is not how to resolve a specific issue but more about deciding which approach to adopt (in a broader context).

I'm working on a JS text editor which should work with BiDi text and custom 'markers'.

Example:
[image: BiDi contenteditable div]

I've made a simple test here in order to test some of the situations described below: https://jsfiddle.net/vskmg1v4/1/

```
<div contenteditable id="editor" dir="rtl"><span class="text" dir="ltr">Hello</span><span class="text" dir="rtl">مرحبا</span><span class="text" dir="ltr">world</span></div>
```

BiDi support on modern browsers is far from being perfect. I've found a few things which are not handled correctly in Chrome (haven't tested each case in Safari and Firefox yet):

1. I didn't find any effective way to control how neutral/weak-direction characters are displayed in BiDi context. Hence the use of a SPANs with specific text direction (`dir` attribute) (see the example above).
2. In RTL context, setting the `dir="rtl"` attribute is not enough: the direction of the caret is backward (= the same direction of LTR context, which is wrong). The strange thing is that the offset inside the Range object is correct.
3. When inside a `contenteditable` element and jumping from an RTL to an LTR element and vice-versa using the arrow keys, the caret seems to skip one position. As you can see in the JSFiddle above, you can't get the caret to move at the end of the RTL span, as it jumps at the beginning of the parent div (beginning = end of the element since its direction is RTL).
4. Navigation via arrow keys is broken (you can't move inside the SPAN containing "world")

For some of these behaviors, I've found the solution, just capturing the "keydown" event and forcing the caret to move like it's supposed to. Anyway, that doesn't fix all the problems above and introduces new ones.

What I'm asking is:

1. I looked at TinyMCE and other WYSIWYG editors and from what I can see they use some sort of fake caret. Is that the only way to work around these inconsistencies? How should I implement it?
2. Will the solution be conservative enough considering browser changes and bugs that will inevitably be introduced in the future?

PS: browser compatibility is not a major concern to me: IE, Edge, Opera, etc are not going to be supported by design.